# Webstorm 9 missing live templates

Tags: webstorm

In Webstorm 9 name when I do `[type func] + control + j` to bring up live template, the func template does not appear. I have JavaScript ticked on the live templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Settings/Editor/Live Templates/javaScript, select the 'func' template and change 'Applicable in' to `javascript: expression, statement` (tick the '`statement`' checkbox)

Comment: by default it's only available in 'javascript expression' context, so you need to enter 'var foo = ' and then type 'func'

Comment: thanks, my context was: genererateArray: function ()